# Modifying pixel RGBA values of texture using glTexSubImage2D does not update the texture

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have a OpenGL Texture, and I would like to change RGBA values of pixels in the Texture on the run.  I want to do the modification on the CPU side. I would like to create a function to change a pixel in a texture in selected coordinates to a selected RGBA value.

I have tried the following:

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,x,y,1,1,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);
```

where `x` and `y` are the coordinates of the modified pixel and `data` is an int array of red, green, blue and alpha. I however am not sure, if I have used the correct parameters, because the texture is not changing when i use this. I want to create a function, that changes a pixels color in a texture in specified coordinates to a specified color using `glTexSubImage2D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a [Direct buffer](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/nio_buffer_direct.shtml), to commit the data by `glTexSubImage2D`

I recommend to create a `ByteBuffer`, somehow like this:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length);
buffer.put(data);
buffer.flip();
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,x,y,1,1,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,buffer);
```

---

If `data` already is a direct buffer, but it is a `IntBuffer`, then the 8th parameter of [`glTexSubImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml), which specifies the data type of a single color channel, has to be `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` or `GL_INT`:

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,x,y,1,1,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,data);
```